# CI 3 URL Routing

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to view another page in a click of a button. During first load of the page i can view the page successfully all the css and js is okay. But when i click a link it redirect to another page but i my i can't load the css and the js file.

`<a href="users/login" class="pull-right login">Login / Register</a>` when i click this link it redirects me to http://localhost/sampleproject/users/login but the css and the js failed to load. and in my log in view i have a back button which redirect me to the index

```
<a href="home">Back</a>
```

but when i click the link it goes to http://localhost/sampleproject/users/home which should be http://localhost/sampleproject/home

in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|css|docs|js|system)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

please tell me what is wrong. I'm a newbie in ci. And i want to try to make a new project from scratch. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Codeigniter's method to achieve this. `site_url()` can be used for links

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('home');?>">Back</a>
```

And for assets (CSS, JS, Image Link etc) link use `base_url()`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/style.css');?>">
```

Assuming you have a folder name `assets` in project root directory.

Also make sure that you set

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/sampleproject/';
```

in `application/config/config.php`

Comment: but is it okay to have $config['base_url'] = "/"; How can I achieve it with $config['base_url'] = "/"; sir?

Comment: @PHP.Newbie Read [here](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L6) CI rule of setting that value.

Comment: @PHP.Newbie I would not just have / in base url do `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/sampleproject/;'`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 sir is it a good practice to not have just $config['base_url'] = "/". And why? because In the conpany where I work there website is using $config['base_url'] = "/"?

Comment: @PHP.Newbie In CI3 `base_url` is a must given value with trailing slash. Otherwise your app will contain `host header injection` security risk .

Comment: @Rejoanul Alam thank you sir for your explanation. In the company where i we're using CI2. Thank you very much sir!